# How can I dynamically downscale the bitmap of a wxBitmapButton to fit?

Tags: wxwidgets, wxpython

Lets say I have a `wxBitmapButton` and a text label `wxButton` in the same horizontal `wxBoxSizer`. The bitmap assigned to the `wxBitmapButton` is too big for the button (and stretches it larger).

[image: What I have]

I want the bitmap to be downscaled so that it fits the button exactly, no longer stretching the button size, while the button itself is no smaller than the "standard" button size.

[image: What I want]

I want this downscaling to happen automatically and dynamically. How can I accomplish this?

*I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.4, Python 3.8.2, and wxPython 4.1.0a1 from the [snapshots folder](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/). I have a normal DPI monitor (although I'd want my code to run on both high-DPI and normal monitors).*

---

Minimal example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from base64 import b64decode  
from wx import *


class TestFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._sizer = BoxSizer(HORIZONTAL)


        button1 = BitmapButton(self)  # I want button1 to be the same size as the other buttons in the sizer, and for the bitmap to downscale to fit

        data = b64decode(''.join([  # 64x64 px PNG
            'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABA',
            'CAMAAACdt4HsAAAANlBMVEUAAAAAAAAA',
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC3',
            'dmhyAAAAEXRSTlMArNkZmwdF04UT9+zS',
            'pndhKrYPNwAAAABsSURBVFjD7ZZJCoAw',
            'EAQ1Olnc5/+fVfAaJFAHCXTdqyCZSw9C',
            '9IDFaMQvyT1NIJD9IYDC7rBwOi3MKqig',
            'wh+FksdvwltYr7pvmzeyWDUQvZkDB/AT',
            '6CfSM8qXLx/4cOLQkUVnHh2aeOoK0QE3',
            'Edkb36fiI5sAAAAASUVORK5CYII='
        ]))

        bmp = Bitmap.NewFromPNGData(data, len(data))
        button1.SetBitmap(bmp)

        # If uncommented, this bit of code will simulate the effect I want
        # img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
        # scaled = img.Scale(17, 17, IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        # button1.SetBitmap(scaled.ConvertToBitmap())


        button2 = Button(self, label='MyButton')
        button3 = Button(self, label='MyButton')
        button4 = Button(self, label='MyButton')


        self._sizer.Add(button1, 0, ALL, 5)
        self._sizer.Add(button2, 0, ALL, 5)
        self._sizer.Add(button3, 0, ALL, 5)
        self._sizer.Add(button4, 0, ALL, 5)


        self.SetSizer(self._sizer)


def main():
    app = App()

    frm = TestFrame(None)

    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what platform? Are you running on the HighDPI monitor? What version of wxWidgets/wxPython do you use? It also would be helpful to see the code...

Comment: @Igor I've taken your suggestions into account and re-wrote my question; please have a look.

Comment: While I appreciate where you're going with this, I think you may be making a rod for your own back. What is the "standard" button size and what are the limits on the original image size to be adjusted? It's probably less painful to get the image size pre-prepared rather try to fit round pegs into square holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxButton` won't do image scaling for you, you need to resize the bitmap yourself. This is not terribly difficult, as you can just use `wxImage::Size()` or `wxImage::Resize()` for this, but it might give non-ideal results for small images with straight lines like the ones you use, which is why it's usually better to have a few pre-rendered bitmaps and choose the most suitable among them instead.

In any case, you still need to know the size to use. It should normally be returned by [wxArtProvider::GetSizeHint()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/classwx_art_provider.html#adfcca5fc919f1be4a95cc5ccb63f1cae), although I admit that I'm not sure if it works correctly when using non-default DPI under macOS (but if it doesn't, it should be reported as a bug and fixed).

Comment: What do I need to call to derive a `wxArtProvider` from a `wxBitmapButton`? I have searched everywhere but found nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what do you mean. You don't derive `wxArtProvider` from `wxBitmapButton` (or anything else), you just use it.

Comment: Err, no, sorry, I meant the `wxArtClient` that `wxArtProvider::GetSizeHint()` wants as the first argument. (This is what happens when I don't get enough sleep.)